# GoogleTV Local App - API to change volume (up/down) of connected TV/AVR?

Tags: android, google-tv

I am writing an App that plays media on Google TV. I want to control volume up/down from inside my App. I tried the following code and here are my test results -

1. Does NOT work on Google TV "box type" products (e.g. Sony NSZ-GS7) -
   does not change volume of connected TV or AVR.
2. On Google TV "embedded in TV" type products (e.g Sony NSXGT1), it changes volume of the TV itself, did not test AVR yet on this setup
3. Works fine for Volume up/down on phones/tablets (e.g Nexus 4)

   ```
   void volume_up(Context context){
     private AudioManager audio = null;

     audio = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
     audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
   }
   ```

What API do I need to call to make #(1) scenario above to work ?
I do not want to use Anymote protocol since it requires pairing & user interaction for pairing which I do not want.